# Calculate Fisher information of $n$ independent random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, proof-explanation, fisher-information

> Let be $X:=\left(X_1,\dots, X_n\right)$ a vector of independent random variables and $P_X(\theta)=f(X_1,\theta)\cdot f(X_2,\theta)\dots \cdot f(X_n,\theta)$ their probability distribution. We assume that all $f(X_i,\theta)$ are differentiable and strictly positive. Compute the Fisher information $I_P(\theta):=\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{d \ln\left(P_X(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)^2\right)$.

There is one important step in our sample solution which I don't understand

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)^2\right)\overset{???}{=}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)^2\right).
$$

I made some simple example to get an idea of it but it seems that the summands for $1\leq i\neq j\leq n $ that consists of
$$2\cdot\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\cdot\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_j,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)$$ don't disappear. Where is the trick?

---

**My Approach:**

Maybe this works:

First, we recall that if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are indepedent random variables, then functions of those random variables, $F(X_1),\dots,F(X_n)$ are again independent random variables (I assume that this statement is well known).

I found a statement in our lecture that says $\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\frac{d \ln\left(P_X(\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)=0$, where $X$ is a random variable or a vector of random variables.
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)^2\right)=\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}-0\right)^2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}-\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{V}_{\theta}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}_{\theta}\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)+2\sum\limits_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\text{Cov}\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta},\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_j,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}_{\theta}\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)+0=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}-\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}-0\right)^2\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{d\ln\left(f(X_i,\theta)\right)}{d\theta}\right)^2\right). 
\end{align*}

I am not sure if there is a shorter or more elegant proof. Any hints are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent, we can say that $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2\right)&=&\mathbb{V}_{\theta}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)-\left(\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)\right)^2\\ &=& \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}_{\theta}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}
\right)-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)\right)^2 \\ &=& \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{V}_{\theta}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}
\right) \\ &=& \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2\right)-\left(\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)\right)^2\right] \\ &=& \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left(\left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \ln f(X_i,\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right)^2\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$